# How to make a ISO out of a folder containing Windows Setup Files

Tags: windows-8, boot, iso-image

I copied the Windows 8 CD to my HDD. I want to convert that folder to an ISO and use that to create a bootable USB.

Please tell me how CAN I MAKE ISO IMAGE.

See, my folder in which i have my files:

[image]

Comment: Directly it cannot be done. Some tools are available to make bootable disk. I don't remember its name now. Just search in google.

Comment: @Sathya This question shouldn't be closed, because he wants to know, how to make an ISO-image. Not where he has to put it in.

Comment: @Sathya i asked that one too but I didnt get good answers and it was marked as dupe of a OTHER question! which wasof another problem

Comment: @TORRENTER so edit the dupe and mention why it isn;t

Comment: @Sathya I for got that accounts email IS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to create an iso-image from your windows 8 dvd instead of just copying the files to your hd and then use the windows 7 usb-dvd download tool (that also works with windows 8 images to create your bootable usb.

you can get ISOdisk for creating the iso image from your win8 dvd here: http://www.isodisk.com/ (it's also free)

you can get the windows 7 usb/dvd download tool here: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool#overview

[image: select iso]

[image: select usb device]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you make .iso from these files and burn it to CD you will not be able to make it bootable, as that information must be extracted from .iso file separately.

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: This answer is wrong. Firstly, no-one mentioned burning an ISO to CD. Secondly, it depends on the burning program if support for bootable CD/DVD is available.